# Multiple graphics directory

Tags: graphics, paths

Here is what I am trying to do. I am writing a document which has many figures. In order to manage the figures it is very convenient for me to keep different types of figures in different folders. Now in the .tex file how can I change the graphicspath to the folder that my graphics are in. If there are multiple different folders where my graphics are located then I shall like to change the directory multiple times. Can you suggest how to do this?

Comment: You can find a lot of **related** topics on the right margin of this post.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use `\graphicspath` in the preamble

as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{./img/}{./pictures/}}

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{one}   %picture named one in directory img
    \includegraphics{two}   %picture named two in directory img
    \includegraphics{three} %picture named three in directory pictures
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not with the comma in between.

Comment: The comma might not be strictly needed, but I prefer it because I think it improves readability.

Comment: Well, it's wrong: the argument to `\graphicspath` should be simply a sequence of `{...}` with nothing between them.