# How to combine 2 latex(.tex) files available in different folders from command line?

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I have 2 latex(.tex) files in 2 different locations in my system. Each of these .tex files are including some grapic figures (.eps files) from another directory as follows.

> IntroductionMergedFigures/grachic1 folder has some eps files as `graphics1.eps`, `graphics2.eps` etc. `IntroductionMergedFigures` folder and `.tex` file are in same directory.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=13.5cm, clip = true]{IntroductionMergedFigures/grachic1}
   \caption{Plot of $a$ vs $b$.}
   \label{fig:Cell2}
\end{figure}
```

I had tried t combine 2 pdfs using `pdftk` tool. I worked, I got the combined PDF but I did not get page numbers in sequence.

The 1st PDF had 5 pages and the 2nd PDF had 14 pages and I got combined PDF with 19 pages which had page range as `1-5` followed by `1-14`, not as `1-19`.

And this is my problem. Please suggest me any way to combine/merge 2 .tex files available in different locations so that when I compile it using `latex` command, it should generate PDF with proper page numbering.

Thanks.

Comment: see answer in this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224930/multiple-graphics-directory

Comment: A quick solution can be to add `\setcounter{page}{6}` after `\begin{document}` in your second file, and concatenate the two files with `pdftk`.